# In which Java class should I wrap my XML file to have the simplest process of saving this XML file to disk

Tags: java, xml, xsd, wsdl

I am creating WSDL file to my web service. I need to choose `xmime:expectedContentTypes` of my XML attachment. Depending on which `xmime:expectedContentTypes` I choose my attachment will be converted into corresponding Java class. I.e. if I set`application/xml` as `xmime:expectedContentTypes` parameter it will map my attachment to `javax.xml.transform.Source` class.

I need to know which Java class allows the simplest process of saving XML file wrapped in that class object into a disk. Then I can choose corresponding `xmime:expectedContentTypes` value.